# Changed owner of /etc folder, can't use sudo anymore

Tags: permissions, system-recovery

I changed owner of /etc folder by accident when I was doing work on web server and now owner of /etc folder and all of its subdirectories is www-data. I can't use sudo anymore for anything and in recovery mode console restarts after like 30 seconds and then it freezes. Is there any way for me to fix this without reinstalling ubuntu.

Comment: Restore the `/etc` folder from the backup. You do have a backup, haven't you? ;)

Comment: Suggest : Get access as root from a live-CD or a live USB stick. And  : `# chown root:root /etc/`

Comment: I do not have a backup... I'll try using live CD to get access as root

Comment: Knud's comment is actually the best *answer* so far, and easiest to perform. Just note that you have to perform the `chown` command to the `etc` folder of your machine, not the `/etc` folder of the live image.

Comment: maybe you can login as root in a separate virtual console. then you wont need to reboot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe searching a little more: https://superuser.com/questions/501818/changing-ownership-without-the-sudo-command#501824

> Reboot, hold down right shift key to bring up the grub2 boot menu. Then follow these instructions to enter single user mode.
>
> [How do I boot into single user mode from grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub)
>
> In single user mode you can fix the file permissions because you are
>   automatically the root user.
>
> Generally speaking, if it's just the file ownership that changed.  You
>   can run:
>
> ```
> chown -R root:root /etc
> ```
>
> That will change ownership and group back to the default root.
>
> I have an ubuntu server 12.04 LTS here and there are a small number of
>   files/directories beneath /etc that have a different group ownership. 
>   Aside from this, all files are owned by root.  The files with the
>   different group ownership are:
>
> ```
> /etc:
> -rw-r----- 1 root daemon   144 Oct 26  2011 at.deny
> drwxr-s--- 2 root dip     4096 Aug 22 12:01 chatscripts
> -rw-r----- 1 root shadow   697 Oct 31 12:58 gshadow
> -rw-r----- 1 root shadow  1569 Oct 31 13:00 shadow
>
> /etc/chatscripts:
> -rw-r----- 1 root dip  656 Aug 22 12:01 provider
> ```
>
> So you can run the chgrp command on those files after initially
>   running chown first. Then you should have everything restored back to
>   how it should be.  It shouldn't take an average user more than 10mins.
>
> ```
> e.g. 
>   chgrp shadow /etc/shadow
> ```
>
> Oh and one final step.  After you've done the changes reboot.
>
> ```
> /> reboot
> ```

Comment: Note that changing ownership may have removed setuid/setgid bits (such as the setgid bit on the chatscripts directory), and these will also need to be restored.

Comment: Whoa, no, don't run `chown root:root`. This changes the group ownership of files. Changing everything then restoring a few files is a terrible idea. If only the owner is bad, restore only the owner.